# Power connectors for very long LED strips

Tags: power, led

I'm working on LED project at home where I'm installing Neopixels LED strips along the top and underneath my cabinets, so basically in 2 long strips.

Because I may need to disconnect things (e.g. get at the controller) I would like all the connections to have some sort of connector. I was looking at the JST connectors but they are only rated for 3A.

The longest strip is 4 meters long (4meters x 30 leds/m x 60mA = 7.2 Amps) which is way more.

Any suggestions on what sort of connectors/wires to use?

Thanks a tonne!

Comment: Look at molex ones like older PC connectors.

Comment: 60mA is that a RGB LED strip?

Comment: Yeah RGB LED strip

Comment: I agree with @Majenko, 11Amps, ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend screw terminals or Molex connectors.

Ref.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not calculating the wrong current? That's really high! I believe 10mA or 20mA should be enough for each LED and also I don't see why the lenght should have such an impact on this case. If that's the case, then 300mA or 600mA would be your maximum current and you wouldn't have any trouble using the connector you mentioned. You should check the LED strip datasheet and see the power specifications.

Comment: 10-20mA is typical, but 60mA is the max, full bright white for most of these LEDs.

Comment: Even so, considering the lenght is not a factor in this case the maximum current would not be higher than 1.8A

Comment: My understanding of electronics isn't very great. Could you elaborate on why length isn't a factor? I was under the impression that any connection/wire would need to support whatever current is passing through. Because there are so many LEDs, there is more current draw and any connection would need to support that higher amperage

Comment: @amorimph 4m x 30 LEDs/m x 3 colors x 20mA = 7,2A

Comment: Oh I think I see the confusion. The LED strip is 30 LEDS per meter. Not 30 total which is likely what you interpreted

Comment: Oh, I see! Indeed, if it's 30LEDs/m you would have a current of 7.2A . Sorry for the misinterpretation. You are correct to assume the wiring has to support the current, but since you are working with only 4m, dimensioning the diameter of the wire should be enough. The bigger the area of the wire's transversal section, the lower the resistance and therefore the higher the current.

Comment: Yes, 20mA per led DIODE. Each RGB led has 3 diodes/colors. Hence 60mA.